# Bug In Ruby Interpretor

Tags: ruby, macos

I am having a problem on my macbook pro when I run certain terminal commands.  It seems to be tied to Ruby.  I am on Yosemite 10.10.3.

I am using RVM for my ruby/rails stuff. Today I tried to run a 'sass watch' while working on some Foundation learning stuff.  When I run the command and I get the following:

```
dhcp-uris-3626:foundation johndcowan$ sass --watch
ruby(3631,0x7fff7d721300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7faac2801808: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

When running the same sass --watch command on a subsequent time, I got a bit more info:

```
dhcp-uris-3626:foundation johndcowan$ sass --watch
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p318 (2012-02-14 revision 34678) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

I was using ruby-2.0.0-p247.  I tried switching to ruby-1.9.2-p318 and running >> gem install sass.  That also bombs when running sass --watch.  When I switched to using ruby-1.9.3-p125 and ran gem install sass, everything works fine.   Go figure.

I tried updating RVM, to no help.

I do not know how to fix the problem I am seeing and am hoping someone here can assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-install gem because it have native extension which usually related to correspond ruby version used during compilation of it. In some configurations (i.e. when you use `vendor/bundle` directory for store application gems) when you switching between ruby versions you can still use the gem installed with other ruby version.

Comment: Thanks,  You are saying to run >> gem install  (?).  Do I need to do this generically or for each ruby version inside rvm?

Comment: Just try to uninstall and install this gem. For any case you can do it for each ruby version but this is not required because RVM using different gemsets for different ruby versions. I think you problem can be related to shared gems i.e. installed to `vendor/bundle` or in system gemset.

Comment: curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install ruby 2.0.0

Comment: The last comment is two commands the seems to have worked.  I updated my rvm and then did rvm install ruby 2.0.0.  Just trying to do a reinstall of 2.0.0 would not connect to the url for downloading the gem zip.  I guess updating rvm did the trick to allow it to work.